# Editing associative array while retaining reference for preparation to JSON encode

Tags: php, json

Is there any common way to edit associative array while retaining reference to original array and making the array be prepared for JSON encode?

An easy way is to rearrange array to new one, but I am thinking that better practice is to go recursively and edit it live.

Comment: Generally it is not possible to modify something while at the same time keeping a reference to its original state, without duplicating either the contents, or at least the ordering of the contents by some kind of identifier.

Comment: `$a=array('1'); $a[2]='2';` This is editing array, while retaining reference.

Comment: i don't even get why you want to use recursion, and tbh i think your code in the comment above is a bad practice, the most important thing in coding is reducing complexity, that is, making code clear even if it takes you more lines to write, so imo do that instead of thinking of what you just asked

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function for live editing JSON array with PHP:

```
function editJSON(&$target, &$aimer){
    $found = false;
    $result = 0;

    foreach($aimer as $ak => $av){
        foreach($target as $tk => $tv){
            if ($tk == $ak){

                $found = true;
                $result = 1;
                if (is_array($tv) && is_array($av)) editJSON($target[$tk], $aimer[$ak]);
            }

            if (!$found && is_array($tv)) $result += editJSON($target[$tk], $aimer);
        }

        if ($found && !is_array($av)) $target[$ak] = $av;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Its fast and tested:

```
$target = array(    'z'=>array('v'=>1, 'c'=>2, 'g'=>3),
                    'b'=>array(
                        'a'=>array(
                            'b'=>array('g'=>array('c'=>11, 'd'=>13), 'b'=>array('x'=>91, 'y'=>92)),
                            'e'=>array('m'=>2)
                        )
                    ),
                    'd'=>array(
                        'a'=>array(
                            'b'=>array('g'=>array('c'=>11, 'd'=>13))
                        )
                    )
                );
$aimer = array(     
                        'a'=>array(
                            'b'=>array('g'=>array('c'=>998, 'hh'=>999))
                        )

                );


echo 'Target array:';
echo '<br />';
print_r($target);
echo '<br />';
echo 'Aiming array:';
echo '<br />';
print_r($aimer);
echo '<br />';
$result = editJSON($target, $aimer);
echo 'Resulting array:';
echo '<br />';
print_r($target);
echo '<br />';
echo 'JSON has been modified ' . $result . ' times.';
```

Will output:

Target array:

Array ( [z] => Array ( [v] => 1 [c] => 2 [g] => 3 ) [b] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [g] => Array ( [c] => 11 [d] => 13 ) [b] => Array ( [x] => 91 [y] => 92 ) ) [e] => Array ( [m] => 2 ) ) ) [d] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [g] => Array ( [c] => 11 [d] => 13 ) ) ) ) )

Aiming array:

Array ( [a] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [g] => Array ( [c] => 998 [hh] => 999 ) ) ) )

Resulting array:

Array ( [z] => Array ( [v] => 1 [c] => 2 [g] => 3 ) [b] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [g] => Array ( [c] => 998 [d] => 13 [hh] => 999 ) [b] => Array ( [x] => 91 [y] => 92 ) ) [e] => Array ( [m] => 2 ) ) ) [d] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [g] => Array ( [c] => 998 [d] => 13 [hh] => 999 ) ) ) ) )

JSON has been modified 2 times.

EDIT: Added functionality for adding values to array and counting edits.

Comment: This is not JSON modification, this is just PHP array modification.

Comment: Is it JSON array associative array?

Comment: Well, than I made mistake with naming function. It would be better named like editing array for preparation for JSON encode. Or something different?

Comment: Yes, i think this probably confused others on your intention, you would get more input if you changed the title of your post and make it a little more clear.